# Failed Host Lookup for certain image links

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add network images that users submit to my app via link.

```
return Image.network('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgta5mod.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F12%2FLos-Santos-Customs-Extension-14.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=849a89cdeb334c0394a0dc69b23915a3235120d13fdc649d76e79c947560adc1&ipo=images');
```

This image will give me a "Failed Host Lookup" exception

While this one won't:

```
return Image.network('https://staticg.sportskeeda.com/editor/2022/12/e7b31-16700956896704.png?w=840');
```

Something I've noticed (in case it helps) is that images hosted on Github will behave nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Looking up your images, the first has a .bin extension while the last has .PNG ... I think Image widget support only global image extensions like jpg,PNG, and so on... Try converting your image to a jpg format and try again

Comment: Hmm... I feel like now the problem becomes that the average user won't catch onto that.

Comment: Are you trying to get images from users ?